# How to do not to open keyboard when pressing suffix icon in TextFormField in flutter

Tags: flutter

When suffix icon is pressed, keyboard is appeared.I don't want to open keyboard when pressing suffix in TextField in flutter. How should I do not to open keyboard when pressing suffix?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

a complete code for TextField would be something like :

```
TextField(
                        controller: controller,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  controller.clear();
                                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                                });
                              },
                              child: Icon(Icons.send)),
                          hintText: 'Type Here ',
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

1. final _focusNode = FocusNode();
2. ```
                     TextFormField(
                       focusNode: _focusNode,
                       decoration: InputDecoration(
                           suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                         child: Icon(
                           Icons.remove_red_eye,
                           color: Colors.white,
                         ),
                         onTap: () {
                           _focusNode.unfocus();
                           _focusNode.canRequestFocus = false;
                         },
                       )),
                     )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an issue with that [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36948).
Some workaround to use CupertinoTextField or simply use Stack with TextField and Icon.
Answered from phone so i cant supply with snippet of code.

Comment: I also tried CupertinoTextField but it doesn't work. I will try Stack with TextField and Icon as you suggest.Thanks.

Comment: I tried CupertinoTextField but it did't worked..... :/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve your problem

```
TextFormField(
                  enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: idCardController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Id Card Number',
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

                        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                          currentFocus.unfocus();
                        }
                      },
                      icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.qrcode_viewfinder, color: statusBarColor,),
                    ),
                  ),
```